# Retrofit 2: Setting Timeouts With No Effect

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

i am using the following:

```
 implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0"

fun getOkHTTPClient(time: Int, interceptor: Interceptor): OkHttpClient {

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
           .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .callTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
        return client.build()
    }

retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("$url/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
```

If i change the timeouts to 10 seconds, 20, 50, 500 etc.... the effect is the same. the call timeout is not obeying these rules.

Am i missing something?

Note: i am using Asynchronous requests if it helps in debugging the case

Comment: Do you mean that the connection gets interrupted before a timeout?

Comment: No, the connection is not getting interrupted while it should be since its taking more than the set amount of seconds

Comment: does your interceptor manipulate the timeouts? If not you could try to add the timeouts in the interceptor, just to see if it's working.

Comment: @mmi how do i add the timeouts in the interceptor? i only add some headers in it

Comment: @rashad.z you can call `.withConnectTimeout(timeout, unit)` etc. on the chain before calling `.proceed()` [see this issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2561). But you are using the most recent OkHttp(3.12.0) & Retrofit(2.5.0), right?

Comment: just tried it and also with no luck

.addInterceptor { chain ->

                    chain.withConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    chain.withReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    chain.withWriteTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    chain.proceed(
                    chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("Accept", StaticVars.JSON_HEADER_REQUEST)
                        .header("Authorization", Security.getEncryptedPass())
                        .build()
                )

Comment: But you are using the most recent OkHttp(3.12.0) & Retrofit(2.5.0), right?

Comment: @mmi yes i am using the following  implementation  
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'

Comment: Please check this answer, it worked for me. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62746271/1164529 
You may just only need to comment out the callTimeout method there.